# "<" and "§" keys mixed up in OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout, osx-lion

I'm using a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 (SWE) in OS X and have a problem. My "§" and "<" key have changed position which is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Microsoft software for OS X [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/B2M-00012#support) (DMG IntelliType Pro 8.1 for Mac) and install, restart your computer and the set it up as suiting for your region (ISO EU in your case). When you're all done with that the < and § keys should no longer be mixed up and as an bonus you gain all the functionality from the extra keys on your keyboard.